# Java ternary operator on simple binary search problem

Tags: java, binary-search, conditional-operator

How can I refactor this code to NOT include "int ans =" I'd like to keep the ternary operator. Since int ans is not actually the answer it makes no sense to keep it this way.

What would be the correct way to use the ternary operator to change the left / right values?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] nums = {-1, 0, 3, 5, 9, 12};
        System.out.println(search(nums, 0));

    }

    public static int search(int[] nums, int target) {
        int middle, left = 0, right = nums.length - 1;
        while (left <= right) {
            middle = left + (right - left) / 2;
            if (nums[middle] == target) return middle;
            int ans = (nums[middle] < target) ? (left = middle + 1) : (right = middle - 1);
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Additionally, when I remove 'int ans = ', the code doesn't compile.

Comment: If `ans` has no usages in the above code, can't it just be removed"? I'm not really sure where this question is going. Could you provide a brief description of the intended purpose of `ans`?

Comment: Convert the ternary operator to an `if` statement?

Comment: That makes sense! That's how I wrote it first but was curious if this is possible via the ternary operator?

Comment: You cannot have a ternary operator as a standalone expression. It's the same as a bare-bones `i + 1;` which also won't compile on its own

Comment: It's more so a question on if we can use the ternary operator without having to assign the value to a variable? Within my code the row with the ternary operator would ideally exclude "int ans ="

Comment: @QBrute Thanks! That's what I was wondering, I'm mostly a javascript developer and have found that within that language we can simply use the ternary operator without having to assign the value to anything. Example boolean ? return 1 : return 0;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditional operator can only be used as part of an expression. An expression cannot stand on its own, but needs to be part of a statement. Assigning a variable is a statement. Computing a value and not storing it, is not. Convert the expression to an statement:

```
int ans = (nums[middle] < target) ? (left = middle + 1) : (right = middle - 1);
```

Becomes:

```
if (nums[middle] < target) {
  left = middle + 1;
} else {
  right = middle - 1;
}
```

If you want to save a few key strokes:

```
if (nums[middle] < target) left = middle + 1;
else right = middle - 1;
```

Relevant links to the JLS:

- [JLS 14.5 Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.5)
- [JLS 14.8 Expression Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8)
- [JLS 15.25 Conditional Operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25)

Comment: This is a fantastic explanation, I just posted my own answer too per the comments on this post! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Due to my background with primarily JavaScript/TypeScript, I was trying to come up with a solution in Java similar to this:

```
const binarySearchArr = (arr: number[], target: number): number => {
  let left = 0;
  let right = arr.length - 1;

  while (left <= right) {
    let middle = left + Math.floor((right - left) / 2);

    if (arr[middle] === target) {
      return middle;
    }
    arr[middle] < target ? (left = middle + 1) : (right = middle - 1);
  }

  return -1;
};
```

Per QBrute's comment, the reason I would have to keep "int ans =" is because Java doesn't support using the ternary operator as a standalone expression.

Comment: Java != JavaScript. JavaScript is a lot more flexible in its syntax. `allowed && callMethod();` is valid in JavaScript, but not in Java. Even `callback && callback();` is a valid statement.

Comment: Do you know a good resource to learn why they're different? I'd love to learn why one language supports it and another doesn't

Comment: Why Java and JavaScript are different? Because they are different languages that were created independently. Don't let yourself be confused by "Java" in "JavaScript". This is akin to asking "Why is English different from French?" – Because they are different languages. The language and syntax specifciation for both languages (Java & JavaScript, not English & French) are publically available, knowk yourself out fun reading them :)

Comment: Thanks knittl, I mean regarding the way each language works in the background, why we can do certain things in Java that we can't in JavaScript (and vice-versa).